# ¿Para que sirve el try y catch? en java

Tags: try-catch

En el siguiente código que función ejerce la clase try y catch?

```
package Package;
import java.io.*;

public class Textos {

    public void leer (String nombreArchive) {
        try {

            FileReader r= new FileReader (nombreArchive);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader (r);
            //System.out.println(buffer.readLine());

            String temp="";
            while(temp!=null) {
                temp = buffer.readLine();
                if (temp==null)
                    break;
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

El try catch en programación se utiliza para manejar fragmentos de código que son propensos a fallar, como  puede ser: recibir un valor nulo, convertir un tipo de dato a otro o en tu caso, la lectura de un archivo.

Al leer un archivo que está almacenado en la memoria del dispositivo (interna o externa), se genera un flujo de bits (físicamente  corriente) desde dicha memoria a la memoria RAM. Ese flujo puede verse interrumpido por diferentes razones, lo que causaría que la tarea falle y que el programa se detenga. El try catch lo que hace es asegurarse que aunque la tarea que se esté ejecutando falle, el programa se siga ejecutando y no se detenga.

Si el código que está dentro del try falla, se ejecuta el catch y el programa se sigue ejecutando. Dentro del try se debe de colocar el código que es propenso a fallar y dentro del catch el código a ejecutarse si el try falla, como puede ser un mensaje de error.

El try catch se debe utilizar cuando se tenga un fragmento de código que es propenso a fallar, que se sabe que por una u otra razón puede fallar. Como por ejemplo la conversión de un tipo de dato a otro:

```
try {

    // Convierte un valor de tipo String a int
    int numero = Integer.parseInt("a456");

} catch(Exception e) {

    System.out.println("ERROR: el valor de tipo String contiene caracteres no numéricos");

}
```

En este caso el código que esta dentro del try fallaría y se ejecutaría el código que está dentro del catch. Si no se usará el try catch en este caso, al producirse el error el programa se detendría. Pero al utilizar el try catch, aunque se produzca el error el programa se seguirá ejecutando normalmente.

Comment: muchas gracias compañero

Comment: gracias ahora me a quedado mas claro lo que es el (try) y el (catch)

Answer (score 1):

**Try**=Tratar, **catch**=atrapar,

Básicamente en el segmento de código dentro del `try` estará el proceso que **tratara** de seguir tu programa y en caso de que en este ocurra un error, excepción o falla por algún motivo, entonces `catch` **atrapa** dicho error o *Excepcion* en la variable `e`(**e** es solo el nombre de variable no es obligatorio llamarla siempre así pero si se aconseja).

> **Nota**: Creo que en todo lenguaje de programación la funcionalidad es la misma

Answer (score -1):

Una de las novedades que incorporó Java 7 es la sentencia try-with-resources con el objetivo de cerrar los recursos de forma automática en la sentencia try-catch-finally y hacer más simple el código. Aquellas variables cuyas clases implementan la interfaz AutoCloseable pueden declararse en el bloque de inicialización de la sentencia try-with-resources y sus métodos close() serán llamados después del bloque finally como si su código estuviese de forma explícita.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2018/04/la-sentencia-try-with-resources-de-java/