# Problema calculadora Java (condicionales)

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Calculadora { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Scanner numero = new Scanner(System.in); 
  double numero1; 
  double numero2; 
  double suma; 

  System.out.print("primer entero"); 
  numero1 = numero.nextDouble(); 
  if((numero1 <= 0) || (numero1 >= 0)){ 
    System.out.print("segundo entero"); 
    numero2 = numero.nextDouble(); 
    if((numero2 <= 0) || (numero2 >= 0)){ 
      suma = numero1 + numero2; 
      System.out.printf("el valor es " + suma); 
    } else { 
      System.out.println("Valor invalido"); 
    } 

  } else { 
    System.out.println("Valor invalido"); 
  } 

}
```

Es algo básico por lo que apenas estoy aprendiendo java, mi pregunta es la siguiente. cómo puedo hacer para que cuando el usuario ingrese un valor distinto a uno numérico, no me de un error de "Exception in thread "main"... at java.util.Scanner.throwFor...".

cómo puedo implementar un condicional, que cuando el usuario coloque algo diferente a un valor numérico, arroje "valor inválido" o algo por el estilo. Gracias.

Comment: Saludo!, puedes verificar el tipo: http://lineadecodigo.com/java/validar-si-un-dato-es-numerico-en-java/, lo otro es que investigues sobre try y catch: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96278/para-que-sirve-el-try-y-catch-en-java

Answer (score 0):

mi solución seria la siguiente, como dijo el anterior usuario, deberías implementar el try & catch.
el try se usa para fragmentos de códigos que son propensos a fallar o cuando hay usuarios curiosos. sí el programa que esta corriendo dentro de try falla, en este caso imprime "Valor invalido".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculadora {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numero = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double suma;
    try {
        System.out.println("Primer entero ");
        num1 = numero.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Segundo entero");
        num2 = numero.nextDouble();
        suma = num1 + num2;
        num2 = numero.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("valor suma" + suma);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Valor invalido");
    }
}
```

}