# Try/Catch en Java: No continua ejecutándose el código después de 'capturar' una Exception?

Tags: java

Tenia entendido que una de las ventajas de **Try/Catch** era que el código seguía ejecutándose después de 'capturar' una posible **Exception** *(tal vez esté equivocado)*.

Si fuera cierto, ¿Este código no debería de devolverme el resulta de **"total2 = 10"** después de mostrar el **"No se puede dividir..."**?

Gracias y disculpar la pregunta de novato.

```
class Excepciones{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int primero = 5;
    int segundo = 0;
    int tercero = 5;
    int total = 0;
    int total2 = 0;
    try{
        total = primero/segundo;
        System.out.println("total: "+total);
        total2 = primero+tercero;
        System.out.print("total2: "+total2);  
    } catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero"+e.getMessage());
    }  
}
```

Comment: Al utilizar un bloque de `try|catch` estas envolviendo operaciones para que en caso de ocurrir alguna falla, pueda capturar el error, - que en tu caso sólo se aplica a excepciones de tipo `ArithmeticException` - y detener el proceso, ya que no se puede seguir un flujo si hay una falla medianamente grave en él.

Comment: [¿Para que sirve el try y catch? en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/96279/95505)

Comment: Ok, gracias. Creo entender que en el bloque Try solamente ha de ir la declaración susceptible a lanzar el error.

Comment: Creo que mal interpretaste la difinicion de ***el código seguía ejecutándose después de 'capturar' una posible Exception***. El codigo sí sigue ejecutanse pero con las siguientes instrucciones que coloques despues del try/catch. En tu caso no hay mas codigo por lo tanto la aplicacion termina. Si lo que quieres es volver a repetir lo que esta dentro del try/catch entonces debes de envolverlo en un bucle.

Comment: Genial, gracias a tod@s.

Comment: @xavi Marca la respuesta como aceptada (dando al ✔) si te sirvió o escribe tú una respuesta, pero no modifiques la pregunta para añadir ahí la respuesta. He revertido los cambios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres manejar una excepción pero al mismo tiempo ejecutar una parte del código ya sea manejada o no la excepción o no puedes usa `finally`.

`finally` crea un bloque de código que se ejecutará después de que se haya completado el un bloque try / catch y antes de que se ejecute el código que luego sigue a este bloque. El bloque finally se ejecutará tanto si se tira la excepción como sino. Esto puede ser **útil para cerrar archivos o liberar cualquier recurso** que se hubiera asignado al principio de un método no siendo este el caso. Los archivos, las conexiones de bases de datos y las conexiones de red que no se cierren apropiadamente podrían no estar disponibles para su uso en otros programas.

Se usa este tipo de estructura:

```
try {

    // Instrucciones cuando no hay una excepción

} catch (TypeException ex) {

    // Instrucciones cuando se produce una excepcion

} finally {

    // Instruciones que se ejecutan, tanto si hay como sino hay excepciones

}
```

La cláusula `finally` es opcional, pero cada sentencia `try` necesita como mínimo, una cláusula `catch` o `finally`.

De otra manera o estructura que se podría indicar tu código seria:

```
        try{
            total = primero/segundo;
            System.out.println("total: "+total);
        } catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero "+e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            total2 = primero+tercero;
            System.out.println("total2: "+total2);
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, sí que ha ayudado!