# ¿Cuándo conviene propagar una excepción?

Tags: java, algoritmos, excepciones, buenas-prácticas, try-catch

Siempre habrá que capturarla con un `TRY`-`CATCH`, pero ¿cuándo conviene propagarla para no tener que tratarla directamente en el método y dejarle el `TRY`-`CATCH` a otro método?

Soy novato, si usan algún ejemplo (que agradecería que así fuera) por favor que no sea muy rebuscado.

Comment: Esta pregunta es basada en opiniones, y probablemente termine cerrada, te aconsejo mirar [para que sirve try catch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96278/para-que-sirve-el-try-y-catch-en-java) adicional a eso usualmente en mi caso lo he ocupado cuando he tenido que usar bases de datos más que nada. Puedes entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) y hablar con gente que lleva años en el rubro :)

Comment: Imagina que tu aplicación trata sobre facturas, al recogerlas de la BD y manejar los datos, resulta que ha fallado 1 dato importante como el importe, yo lo que hago es que en el catch, pongo el array a null, y luego compruebo si me ha venido a null, en caso contrario, si el dato que falló era una fecha en formato raro y no se ha podido tratar, le dejo la fecha por defecto, es decir, si es 'delicado,importante' tendrás que abortar,sino deja el valor por defecto, aunque básicamente, harás lo que te manden hacer.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679090/when-to-catch-the-exception-vs-when-to-throw-the-exceptions

Answer (score 6):

Básicamente la elección es sencilla: **Las excepciones deben ser capturadas por los métodos que saben qué hacer con ellas**.

Un ejemplo: Tienes una clase `FileWriter` que crea un fichero con unos datos. La clase no sabe qué importante es la creación del fichero o si es un fichero de muchos. Si tienes una excepción del tipo *no tengo permisos de escritura* debes propagar la excepción.

Por encima tienes una clase que es la que sabe qué datos se están intentando guardar:

- Puede ser que estés guardando los resultados de un proceso complejo y debas avisar al usuario de que no se pueden guardar en ese path, que elija otro.
- Pero puede ser que simplemente es un fichero de log, con lo que puedes mostrar un aviso de que no se guardará el log de la ejecución y seguir trabajando a pesar de ello.

Hay otro caso intermedio: Ha ocurrido un error, se ha lanzado una excepción pero es muy específica y no quieres dar mucha información. Puedes capturarla, obtener la información disponible del error y lanzar otro tipo de excepción más acorde:

```
try {

    ...
   } catch (IncorrectOwnerException exp) {
     logger.warn ("El usuario intenta obtener un recurso que no le pertenece")
     //el usuario no tiene ni que saber que ese recurso existe, hagamos como que no hemos encontrado nada
     throw new NotFoundException(...); //provocará un HTTP 404
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java te da las herramientas necesarias para poder **capturar** y/o **propagar** las excepciones; pero decidir cuándo realizar cada una de estas acciones **dependerá de la lógica de negocio que implementes**.

En términos generales, las excepciones se suelen capturar cuando la ejecución puede continuar pese al error o cuando queramos encapsularla en un tipo de excepción distinto. En otro caso, lo ideal sería propagarla para que finalice la ejecución del thread.

Un ejemplo sencillo podría ser un programa que lea valores numéricos introducidos por el usuario. Si tras n introducciones, el usuario teclea un valor no numérico, podría interesarnos capturar el error, mostrar un mensaje al usuario, y seguir pidiendo valores. O también podría interesarnos dar un error y parar la ejecución, para que el usuario no pueda seguir introduciendo valores.

El tratamiento y gestión de excepciones en Java es un tema muy extenso, te recomiendo que leas algunos artículos sobre la gestión de excepciones y, si tienes alguna duda concreta, la plantees de nuevo de manera más específica.