# Cómo validar y cómo puedo mostrar un mensaje en ventana?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se muestre un mensaje al guardar datos si la fecha no tiene el formato correcto?

Me guarda la fecha pero no me muestra el mensaje al producirse el error.

Mi código actual es como sigue:

```
private void cargarFechaVenta() {

    Calendar miCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    txtFecha.setText(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(miCalendar.getTime())));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Debe ingresar formato valido.", "yyy-MM-dd", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );

}
```

Comment: Es porque no estas validando nada... Y por cierto, debes añadir en los tags que esto es para `Android`

Comment: Esto no es para `Android`. Las etiqueta `java` está bien. Java Swing también tiene elementos con el método `setText`, por lo que bien puede ser una aplicación de escritorio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuación comparto este código esperando que cumpla  con tus requerimientos

En este código uso los bloques try /catch para capturar cualquier error que se produzca en tiempo de ejecución. Puedes encontrar mas información [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96278/para-que-sirve-el-try-y-catch-en-java).

```
public void cargarFechaVenta() {

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String fechaTextboxt = txtFecha.getText();
        if (fechaTextboxt.contains("/")) {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        }

        Date fechaIngresada = sdf.parse(fechaTextboxt);
        String fechaValida = sdf.format(fechaIngresada);

        if (fechaTextboxt.equals(fechaValida)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha válida", "Exitoso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha no válida", "Error al comparar", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha producido un error al validar la fecha " + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: gracias cheox voy a probar y te comentare luego...mil gracias por tomar tu tiempo llevo dias averiguando jaja

Comment: hola gracias  cheox por tu tiempo llevo dia socn esto...mi duda es que me entrega el mensaje valido cuando pongo yyy-MM-dd ,pero no el incorrecto cuando ingreso dd-MM-yyyy me sigue apareciendo  valido cuando quiero que sea invalido ...

Comment: yo necesito recoger el dato de un campo de txfield llamdo txtfecha. PERO CUANDO LLAMO A ESTE METODO me muestra el mesaje pero si ingreso mal la fecha me dice valido ..

Comment: Amigo ya actualicé el código en base a las nuevas especificaciones de tu último comentario.Disculpa no hacerlo antes pero sólo puedo responder en horas de la noche.

Comment: cheox gracias soy amiga jaja vos sabes uqe el codigo funciona pero cuando pongo en el campo la fecha 2019/12/12 me sigue siendo que es incorrecta . yo lo que quiero es que me diga cuando pongo esa fecha fecha valida. y cuando ponga 12/12/2019 me diga error de formato porque estoy usando el yyyy-MM-dd. y aun asi cuando guardo en mi boton los datos me valida pero no me salta el mensaje de fecha correcta cuando la pongo correcta .. ese es el gran drama jejeje

Comment: Ya  funciona  el código

Comment: genial ! es el que editaste? :)

Comment: Si! el que edité  :)

Comment: Lo pruebas y me avisas vale?

Comment: bueno me salvaste la vida no se como agradecerte mas alla de los votos ...... :D eres mi preferido en este foro :D

Comment: De nada amiga fué un gusto ayudarte   cualquier novedad me cuentas.

Answer (score 1):

Me comentas luego si esto te sirve:

```
private void cargarFechaVenta() {

    Calendar miCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String formato = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
    String fecha = txtFecha.setText(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(miCalendar.getTime())));
    if(formato!= fecha || !fecha.Equals(formato)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Debe ingresar formato valido.", "yyy-MM-dd", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
 }
}
```

Esa sería más o menos la lógica, hace  mucho no programo en Android

Comment: Tu respuesta no añade ninguna verificación de formato. Lo que hace es comprobar si la fecha introducida es el literal `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, cosa que no es una fecha. Además, la comprobación `fecha != formato` no tiene sentido, ya que solo estás comprobando si las dos variables hacen referencia al mismo objeto (`OID`), no si tienen el mismo contenido. Cualquier variable que contenga una fecha va a contener una referencia distinta de la referencia al objeto guardado en `formato`, por lo que el mensaje de error se muestra siempre.

Comment: fraco gracias y equis gracias aunque estoy progrmando en java ....no en android jeje!